# How do you manage SSH keys?

Tags: ssh

I have a server with multiple users which each have multiple authorized SSH keys. Is there any effective way (command line utility?) to keep track of which key belongs to who and to quickly remove/add keys (apart from ssh-copy-id)?

Comment: shell scripts can easily track login times from logs and manipulate the files in .ssh...I know that's not what you are looking for, so it's a comment not an answer

Comment: Use the last part of each lines in `.ssh/authorized_keys` is intended for comments (from `man sshd`: "Protocol 1 public keys consist of the following space-separated fields: options, bits, exponent, modulus, comment.  Protocol 2 public key consist of: options, keytype, base64-encoded key, comment."). And to answer the question, I use `vim` but any editor should do it.

Comment: Of course if every user do have separate user account, there is no problem, as long as all entries are in everyone's home folder (or actually in .ssh/authorized_keys, but anyway).

Comment: @shellholic, you have a good answer. Post it so it can be marked as such :)

Comment: @djeikyb ok, done, but I should complete a bit

Answer (score 3):

You can use the last part of each lines in `.ssh/authorized_keys` is intended for comments. From `man sshd`:

> Protocol 1 public keys consist of the
>   following space-separated fields:
>   options, bits, exponent, modulus,
>   comment. Protocol 2 public key consist
>   of: options, keytype, base64-encoded
>   key, comment.

And to answer the question, I use `vim` but any editor should do it.

My comments usually contains:

- creation date
- physical location: creation computer / USB stick (I prefer not to move private key but generate/revoke them and know where they are)
- 1-2 words about purpose (for which login, for which client, for which script)

Answer (score 3):

I'd checkout the [Monkeysphere](http://web.monkeysphere.info/) project. It uses OpenPGP's web of trust concepts to manage ssh's authorized_keys and known_hosts files, without requiring changes to the ssh client or server.

Answer (score 0):

There's also [`ssh-import-id`](http://manpg.es/ssh-import-id), which can securely import users' SSH public keys from [Launchpad.net](http://launchpad.net).

Answer (score 0):

Bastillion - https://www.bastillion.io

Users manage their own SSH keys based on profiles that have been assigned to them.

https://www.bastillion.io/docs/using/keymanagement/